# Looking for InDesign Help

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm a decent PhotoShop artist, mostly using it for exhibition pieces of music artists I listen to and promotional flyers. I'm looking to take my craft to another level by learning InDesign so that I can also begin doing better logos. I've tried Ch-Ch-Check It Clan on YouTube, and some others, but I didn't quite grasp what they were doing. Does anyone have any tips on how a true beginner can get the basics quickly? I'm a visual learner, so I'd much rather not use a book.

Comment: Hi Dre and welcome to the community. Stack Exchange sites are not very conductive for "list of tips" questions like these. We would be better suited to help you with any specific aspects of guides or tutorials that you may struggle to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

First if you want to do logos, you should consider Adobe Illustrator first.

Maybe have a look at the [Adobe's website](http://adobe.com/) and learn about their different software before throwing yourself into focusing on learning one only. They work all together, so eventually you'll need to learn a few!

But if you need to learn InDesign from scratch... I'm not really sure where to begin actually. **Doing design isn't just about placing elements in a software, there's much more to it.** Your question is a bit like asking Mozart how to play music. (not that we're all Mozarts but lot are master designers here!)

Most designers paid for a training in a design school first and spent a few months or years learning. And then still keep learning since software evolve as well. Therefore you can't expect to learn everything easily on a video or online websites, and it would be hard to give you the best resource for this.

If you are visual, I strongly suggest you to look for a design school and teachers; **it's respectful to the profession and to your future clients** who will put trust (and money, and hope) that you know what you're doing!

For visual training videos, have a look at lynda.com. I can't tell you how good they are since I don't like watching tutorials but it's a good reference in general.

This is one series to get you started with Illustrator:

http://www.lynda.com/Illustrator-tutorials/Illustrator-CC-Essential-Training-2015/370378-2.html

This is one series to get you started with InDesign:

http://www.lynda.com/InDesign-tutorials/Introducing-InDesign/147822-2.html

**PS:** If you don't like reading or using books, it's possible you'll have a miserable life as a designer! Adobe have a big help file but not many videos, and the experts who create tutorials often don't create video versions.